# equivalence relation proof {(x, y) ∈ R^2 ∶ x − y ∈ Q}

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science

Prove that
 {(x, y) ∈ R^2 ∶ x − y ∈ Q} is an equivalence relation on the set of real numbers, where Q
denotes the set of rational numbers.

Hi guys, not really sure how to start this question. My first thoughts are to check if its reflexive,symmetric, antisymmetric,transitive. After that, not too sure where to go.

Comment: So, what does it mean for a relation to be reflexive, symmetric, and/or transitive?  How about you define those properties in your post?

Comment: Hi, welcome! Could you write what have you tried? Where did you get stuck? . To prove that some relation is an equivalence relation, you have to prove that it's only reflexive, symmetric and transitive.

Comment: What would you know if  its "reflexive, symmetric, anti-symmetric, transitive"?  How about this, what is the definition of "Equivalence relation"  when in doubt, write down the definitions.

Answer (score 1):

Reflexive

$xRx,  x-x= 0$ and $0\in \mathbb Q$

Symmetric

$xRy\implies yRx$  if $x-y$ is rational then $y-x = -(x-y)$ is also rational.

Transitive

$xRy, yRz\implies xRz$

$(x-z) = (x-y) + (y-z)$ and a $\mathbb Q$ is closed under addition so (x-z) must be rational

Comment: Note that the same proof works if we replace $\,\Bbb Q\,$ be any subset of $\,\Bbb R\,$ containing $0$ and closed under negation and addtion, i.e. any additive subgroup. Equivalently we need only test that the subset is nonempty and closed under subtraction (by the subgroup test). The innate algebraic structure will become clearer when one studies quotient groups.